# DRIVELOCK password

Tags: passwords

I changed my computer user name and password.
When I logged in it was still OK. But when I restarted again it did not accept my password,
it says wrong password or incorrect.
Then the IT department who checks it said I messed up by renaming my user name and password.
Is changing the admin password wrong? Then he uninstalled / reinstalled Windows 7 and encountered a drivelock password (we cannot go into the BIOS because of it). Then he said it is because we cannot input my password, is the drive lock password related to the password I changed?

Comment: **1.** *I changed my computer user name and password.*: do you mean you changed your Windows 7 session credentials? **2.** *Is changing the admin password wrong?*: Admin of what? Because this too confusing: from the first statement we are likely to believe you changed your Windows 7 session. **3.** How did you change the password of whom? I insist on the *how* and *who*. because, as it is asked, your question is unclear and too broad

Comment: This is more of a question about how to correctly use a specific software product and not so much about security. I nominated it for migration to superuser.com.

Comment: better to be migrated to superuser.stackoverlow.com